# Leaflet - Define maxNativeZoom based on specific regions

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, openstreetmap

I'm trying to figure out how I can specify the `maxNativeZoom` multiple times for different regions/bounds.

Our tile server has more detailed tiles available for some parts of Europe. I would like to allow the user to zoom in on these regions, but not on the less detailed region.

- We have most of Europe available until zoom level 13.
- Most of the Netherlands is available at zoom level 16.
- Some parts of the Netherlands (cities) are even available at zoom level 17.

Currently, I set my `maxNativeZoom` to 17. This way, the user can zoom in on the cities and retrieve the detailed tiles. Sadly, for the rest of Europe, this will result in gray tiles and a lot of 404 errors.

Is there a way, maybe with a `moveend` JavaScript trigger, to have different `maxNativeZoom` levels for specific bounds? Perhaps this is not smart to do, if so, please also let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

While I do not see a practical way of having different `maxNativeZoom` on the same Tile Layer depending on areas, you would probably be interested in [Leaflet.TileLayer.Fallback](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.TileLayer.Fallback) plugin as a workaround:

> Replaces missing Tiles by scaled lower zoom Tiles

[(Demo)](https://ghybs.github.io/Leaflet.TileLayer.Fallback/examples/tileLayerFallback-demo.html)

In more detail:

> TileLayer.Fallback plugin tries to replace each missing tile by its immediate lower zoom equivalent, and if that one is also missing, it goes to lower zoom again; and so on until a tile image is returned by the server

With this plugin, you do not need to explicitly specify the `maxNativeZoom` option. The Tile Layer tries first to get a tile image at the current zoom, but in areas where the server does not have the image for that zoom level and returns a 404 error, the Tile Layer will automatically request a lower zoom instead.

Similar effect as with `maxNativeZoom`, but automatically triggered by 404 error.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the plugin.